# Shortcut to scroll in the build window tool in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I do not want to use the mouse but only the keyboard. 
I use a lot the action shortcut to do that, and I remember a number of shortcuts. But when I do a run and get some errors, I find frustrating I have to use the mouse to gain the focus of the Window Tool `Build` ( the one that is on default without a shortcut into the bottom bar of Android Studio. How can I without the mouse, see the runtime errors, scrolling into the Build tool window?

By the way I experience the same problem with `Logcat`, I gain via tab the access to the above bar functions of `Logcat`, but I cannot scroll Logcat

I tried a lot of commands, even giving a shortcut to `Build` but does not work

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) for future questions like this. I didn't saw the shortCut you were looking for in there.

Comment: of course I saw that, I think is more a bug actually I would like to know if somebody has a workaround